# Should the tags for the closely related PDPs be synonymised or something?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I mean, what *really* is the difference between a PDP-6 and a PDP-10 or DECSYSTEM-20? From the programmers' point of view, not much.

The same goes for PDP-4, -7, -9 and -15.

The same goes for the PDP-5 and -8, and Harris 6120.

For whatever reason, the PDP-11 stayed as -11, despite the huge variation in the product family.

Should the questions about the similar computers be tagged with all the applicable tags, or should the tags be made such that [pdp-7](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdp-7) is synonymous with [pdp-9](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdp-9) et cetera?